# Composer fail installation on PHP path

Tags: php, composer-php, environment-variables

Im trying to install Composer.exe, and it always fail after I choose php.exe file and click next, with an error:

[image]

```
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly [exit code 1]: D:\Software(x86)\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe

Program Output: 'D:\Software' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Thing is: Path to the php.exe is valid. I have php in env variables, so if I run cmd and type in php it runs...
But if open cmd and type in path that I gave to the composer so `D:\Software(x86)\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe`
It respond with `'D:\Software' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` too.

To clarify, I restarted computer after php installation and I after added env variables.
And this is in my env path var: `...;D:\Software(x86)\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\`

> I installed xampp on D:\ Drive and it didnt work too, then I
>   uninstalled it and istalled it on C:\ and it worked... Dunno what was
>   the problem, if someone can explain, please do. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you download and install composer using `.exe` file? and also make sure you point to the `bin` directory in your `path` environment variable.

Comment: @Hari Lamichhane im using composer.exe

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to escape the braces in windows. Either with a backslash or the complete folder with quotes

Comment: I can't please check question again.

Comment: I guess that could be very tricky, as windows is not the perfect environment to develop stuff like php. You could try to install it manually: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows
That should be simpler over all